# Nutch ERROR tika.TikaParser on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nutch, apache-tika

I am running Nutch 2.2.1 on Eclipse Juno SR1 and JRE 1.7.0_25

The PARSE step is failing with this error:

```
2013-08-15 19:35:26,555 ERROR tika.TikaParser - Can't retrieve Tika parser for mime-type application/pdf
2013-08-15 19:35:26,557 WARN  parse.ParseUtil - Unable to successfully parse content
```

It seems like this error is coming from TikaConfig.java because I get an empty iterator:

```
Iterator<Parser> iterator = ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(
    Parser.class, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

The same PARSE call from CYGWIN is successful, I get all PARSERS from Service registry. So maybe the solution is  configuration for Eclipse related to [Service registry.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html)

Nutch-Eclipse is well configured about nutch-site.xml, parse-plugins.xml

I appreciate any idea to solve this.

Comment: Do you have all the Tika jars, and their dependecies correctly on your classpath?

Comment: Yes, I have all dependencies on build path and order, also using same cygwin classpath on VM arguments. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this thread, seems like he had a similar problem and resolved it:

http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Nutch-2-x-Eclipse-Can-t-retrieve-Tika-parser-for-mime-type-application-pdf-td4015896.html

Comment: Thanks @Allan, was not my problem exactly, because I didn´t have the tika parser jar within local/lib dir, however this helped me to find out how to fix my classpath including the folder for parser-tika plugin within eclipse.